# I can't associate my Images to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, image, gallery

I have Pictures which are located at Images/, and the Thumbnails at Thumbnails/, Whatever my problem is that I can't associate my uploaded images to an SQL table, I want to do so to make the up-loader's name appear on the Public_Images page, Without SQL I can do it by getting the username from the $_SESSION['username'], Because it's an personal view it's okay, but now I'm creating a Public_Images page and I couldn't make the uploaded images or the future uploaded images associated to my table Images ... :( !!! You think that I can use the function Substr to extart the user-name from the full adress which is like

```
 ./private_images/images/User/photo-0123456789.jpg
```

Comment: Do you have an `Image` table?  What columns does it have?

Comment: What is your current MySQL schema?  Where are you getting into trouble?  Is it actually checking the existing images and creating the necessary DB entries?

Comment: no idea what you are asking, code could help.

Comment: Images should be just e.g. UUID's on the file system. Any meta data such as file type location (path), etc. should be stored in the database. So subsequent lookups are all done in the DB while the images are elsewhere being served statically to reduce the load on your dynamic http server.

Comment: Yes sure i have a table and here it is http://img577.imageshack.us/img577/2541/sanstitrexc.png